# "There is not + noun" vs "There is no + noun"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I am wondering why in sentences with "There is/are" "not" sounds so unnatural, for example:

> 1. There are not shops in this village.

I assume that the one correct version is

> 2. "There are no shops in this village"

but still I don't have a proper justification.

Comment: There are not any shops in this village. is better.

Comment: You would need to put "any" after "not" in your first example. See this article [No, not a, not any: How to use correctly](https://editorsmanual.com/articles/no-not-a-not-any/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"no"** is used predominantly with nouns: no shops, no clouds, no money...

**"not"** is used predominantly with verbs: (do) not know, (do) not drink, (do) not forget...

So your your assumptions and your sentence number 2 are both correct.

Comment: Thank you for help!